# Simple communication between two node.js application over a local network

Tags: node.js, networking, localhost

I'm writing an app (with NWjs) that I'm running on both my laptop and my PC. What could I use if simply want to exchange some data between those two computers through my app?

The idea is having:

- Machine1 (192.168.1.35): here are the files I can play
- Machine2 (192.168.1.36): i'm interrested in that one file
- Machine1 (192.168.1.35): ok, I'm playing it on 192.168.1.35:3000/0

I was thinking of exposing "here are the files I can play" with a json file hosted by Machine1 somewhere like 192.168.1.35:3000/db.json

Then, read that json with Machine2, chooses one file, and ??? communicate ??? which one it is to Machine1.

Machine1 will then host it on 192.168.1.35:3000/0, and ??? communicate ??? the full path to Machine2.

The "??? communicate ???" part is where I'm stuck. Is there something simple that I could use? Maybe something like the 'net send' windows command (and the part where I can actually read what's been sent and act accordingly).

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some digging, it turns out you can POST to an http server. Here's what I did:

Machine1:

```
let ip = '192.168.1.35';

// create a json
let json = {
  movies:[
    {title: 'my movie 1',
     path: 'D:\Videos\mymovie1.mkv,
     size: 100000},
    {title: 'my movie 2',
     path: 'D:\Videos\mymovie2.mkv,
     size: 100000}
  ]
};

// create a server for GET/POST
let apiServer = require('http').createServer((res,req) => {

  // on GET, serve the json
  if (req.method === 'GET') {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
    res.write(JSON.stringify(json));
    res.end();
  }

  // on POST, check what the Machine2 wants to play
  if (req.method === 'POST') {
    let body = String(); // create body
    req.on('data', data => body += data); // update body with POST content

    req.on('end', () => {
      let file = JSON.parse(body);

      // create a server for serving the file over http
      let playServer = http.createServer((req,res) => {
        res.writeHead(200, {
          'Content-Type': 'video/mp4',
          'Content-Length': file.size
        });

        let readStream = require('fs').createReadStream(file.path);
        readStream.pipe(res);
      });

      // start serving the file on localhost:3001
      playServer.listen(3001);

      // respond to Machine2 where the file is streamed
      res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
      res.write(JSON.stringify({
        url: `http://${ip}:3001`
      }));
      res.end();
    });
  }
});

// start serving the json on localhost:3000
apiServer.listen(3000);
```

Machine2:

```
let available;

// send a GET to Machine1
require('request')('http://192.168.1.35:3000', (err, res, body) => {
  available = JSON.parse(body);
});

// select desired file
let wantedMovie = available.movies[0];

// send a POST to Machine1 saying what I want.
require('request')('http://192.168.1.35:3000', {
  method: 'POST',
  body: JSON.stringify(wantedMovie)
}, (err, res, body) => {
  let url = JSON.parse(body).url;
  // => playback the file from Machine1 via the URL.
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to have HTTP (Node.js) server running on one machine (say machine A) on which you could make HTTP request from other machine (from Node.js application, machine B) and hence communicate between machines. You ll have to expose HTTP request endpoints on machine A's Application. Some good libraries to do so are

- ExpressJS
- RESTify

On top of that, you could make WebSocket interfaces on both machine's Node.js application for a faster event based communication.

Comment: Thanks but that's a little complicated for me